# changing of questions in same text view and getting options

Tags: android, layout, textview

I am developing an quiz based app and i wanted to know how i can do it.I want the text view and layout to remain stagnant only the questions and its options should change when next button is pressed.can some one help me out with this. Thank You in advance. Any help is appreciable

Comment: What you have tried so far? Otherwise many questions from my side: 1) loading Questios/options from database? 2) loading questions/options from Web?

Comment: loading questions and options from db. I have created db file which contains the questions and answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have the layout in place for your quiz:

In your activity you can do something like:

```
Button nextButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.nextbutton);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                question.setText(questions.get(questionNumber));
answersList = new AnswersListAdapter(
                getBaseContext(), splitAnswers[questionNumber], -1 , false);
answers.setAdapter(answersList);

            }
        });
```

AnswersListAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AnswersListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private String [] splitAnswers;
    public AnswersListAdapter(Context context,String [] splitAnswers){
        super();
        this.context=context;
        this.splitAnswers=splitAnswers;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return splitAnswers.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return splitAnswers[arg0];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return splitAnswers[arg0].hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        RelativeLayout root = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.answers_item, null,false);

        TextView label =(TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.label);
        ImageView options=(ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.options);


                label.setText(splitAnswers[position]);
        return root;
    }

}
```

answers_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="2dp" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
    </TextView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/options"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/label"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/label"
        android:background="@drawable/a" >
    </ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You might have to do some customization depening on where exactly your data is coming in from and also few other factors. Hope it helps.

Comment: Options in ImageView? I think TextView suits best to choose particular option.

Comment: @PareshMayani depends for my case when i had a similar scenario i had imageViews provided for each option (a,b,c,d) thats why i mentioned you might have to do some customization depending on your need.

Comment: @rithesh you dont need any permissions to be set in manifest for accessing DB.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reset the text for each textview with a new call to setText() and then if you invalidate() the view it should redraw.  You could just have a side variable then that keeps track of the correct answer for each question.